# How to separate a CVS column by position in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, fixed-width

I have data that I want to separate into 3 columns form the one column in a CVS file.
The original file looks like this:

```
0400000006340000000000965871       
0700000007850000000000336487    
0100000003360000000000444444
```

I would like to separate the columns to resemble the list below, while still preserving the leading zeros:

```
04 0000000634 0000000000965871   
07 0000000785 0000000000336487   
01 0000000336 0000000000444444
```

I can upload the file onto Python, but I don't know which Delimiter or positioning I have to use. The code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd   
df = pd.read_cvs('new_numbers.txt', header=None)
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: You have all rows like this? They are in the format <zeros><number><zeros><number><zeros><number>? You want to "separate them" preserving the leading zeros? Try to edit your question with these informations in mind.

Comment: Yes all rows are like this. I want to preserve the leading zeros.

Comment: `cVs` vs `cSv` - one is Concurrent Versioning System the other is Comma Separated Values. You seem to have used `cvs` everywhere which definitely doesn't exist for `pd.cvs`. Anyway, it's not needed for your case, [see answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67003444/1431750).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the pandas [`read_fwf()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) method - which stands for "fixed-width format":

```py
pd.read_fwf('new_numbers.txt', widths=[2, 10, 16], header=None)
```

which will drop the leading zeroes:

```
   0    1       2
0  4  634  965871
1  7  785  336487
2  1  336  444444
```

To keep them, specify the `dtype` as strings with `object`:

```py
pd.read_fwf('new_numbers.txt', widths=[2, 10, 16], dtype=object, header=None)
```

Output:

```
    0           1                 2
0  04  0000000634  0000000000965871
1  07  0000000785  0000000000336487
2  01  0000000336  0000000000444444
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is no delimiter and you are using fixed lengths.

Access fixed lengths by their position in a list notation.

So for instance:

```
str1 = "0400000006340000000000965871"

str1A = str1[:2]
str1B = str1[3:14]
str1C = str1[14:]
```

I wouldn't particularly bother with pandas for it unless you need a dataframe out the far end.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need pandas to load your text file and read its content (and also, you aren't loading a csv file).

```py
with open("new_numbers.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

What I suggest you is to use `re` module.

```py
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(r"(0*[1-9]+)(0*[1-9]+)(0*[1-9]+)")
```

You can [check here](https://regex101.com/r/TCrHEr/1) the result of this expression on your example.

Then you need to get matches from your lines, and join them with a space.

```py
matches = []
for line in lines:
    match = PATTERN.match(line)
    first, second, third = match.group(1, 2, 3)
    matches.append(" ".join([first, second, third]))
```

At the end, `matches` will be an array of space-separated numbers (with leading zeros).

At this point you can write them to another file, or do whatever you need to do with it.

```
towrite = "\n".join(matches)

with open("output.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(towrite)
```